# Can XSD validate that an element contains references to all definitions of another element

Tags: xml, xsd

Using xsd:key and xsd:keyref, we can validate that a value in one element is defined in another element.  We do this in our schema to ensure that valid values are used, but we would also like to be able to validate that all of the values specified in one element are used in children of another element, i.e.:

```
<elementList>
   <listEntry>Entry1</listEntry>
   <listEntry>Entry2</listEntry>
   <listEntry>Entry3</listEntry>
</elementList>
<elementOperations>
   <operation name="Entry1">Operation1</operation>
   <operation name="Entry3">Operation3</operation>
</elementOperations>
```

In this example, we would like there to be a validation error because there is not an  element whose name attribute specifies Entry2.  Is this possible at all with XSD Schema validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you're not allowing duplicate values in the operation names; in which case simply add another key/keyref pair which points the other way around (i.e. the key is now the operation name).

If duplicates are possible, then you cannot do it with XSD 1.0 alone - Schematron can help you here. Alternatively, if you're working in an environment where XSD 1.1 is supported, then use XSD 1.1's `xsd:assert`.

Comment: This answers the question very well, unfortunately for me, I found out that the XML checking required is actually more complex than the simple example I posted and requires xpath tests, which XSD 1.0 does not allow.